# Optics phenomenon with my glasses?

Tags: optics, visible-light, polarization

When I look through my glasses toward the extreme left, a very odd and intriguing phenomenon occurs: The border of everything I see is lined with a hazy blue lining **on the left** and a hazy yellow lining on the right. *This phenomenon is reversed when I look through my glasses at the extreme right!*

Is this something related to optics (e.g. polarization, refraction, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that different colors of light refract through glass (or whatever your glasses are made of) at different angles. Plain white light contains all other colors within it. When a beam of white light hits your glasses at an angle the yellow/red and blue/violet light separate from the main beam due to their different energy levels (blue/violet high energy, yellow and red low energy). You should actually see red opposite of blue, but I'm guessing you see yellow only because it is more noticeable.

If you had a high quality prism you could get all the colors to separate from one another and create a full rainbow. In fact, you are observing the same phenomena that creates a rainbow, but through your glasses and not a raindrop. Look up prism refraction and you'll see all you need to know.

**Edit**

CarlWitthoft has kindly pointed out below that you are observing what is referred to in optics as "dispersion".

Comment: But why is this phenomenon reversed when I view the extreme left or right? If it was a prism, wouldn't it split light in the same way?

Comment: @HyperLuminal try drawing the ray path thru a prism - you'll see the "bending" will be reversed for rays with angles of entry on the right and left sides of vertical.

Comment: Ian,  you might want to include the fact that you're describing the optics term "dispersion" here. And BTW for a given material used in eyeglasses, the index $n$ for red and yellow light may be about the same in the first place.

Comment: Another search term of interest is "chromatic aberration".

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, if index n for red and yellow were the same then wouldn't red and yellow still be mostly combined and come out white-ish?

Comment: Yeah, maybe :-).  Maybe in the OP's case the red is bent out-of-frame

Answer (score 3):

This is due to [chromatic aberration](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/aber2.html). 
[image: chromatic abberation]

It is dependent on the chromatic dispersion of the material the lense is made of, which is the change of the [index of refraction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/dispersion.html#c1) for each color. [Dispersion](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/dispersion.html#c1) is what causes light to be separated by a prism.

When you keep your head still and move your eyes, you change the position of your retina (i.e. your visual axis) with respect to the optical axis of the lense and thus, with the focal planes of each wavelength.

[image: chromatic aberration] [image: focal planes]

This creates these color fringes around the edges of objects and would explain why the phenomenon is reversed when you look in the opposite direction. This becomes obvious when plotting the path of the light from the edges of the lense to the eye for different wavelengths and their respective focal planes.